# creation of aspect similar to @Transaction in spring

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I was reading [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/aspectj_based_aop_appoach.htm) link but i have a doubt. Here we are defining where the aspect will be getting called e.g. `@Pointcut("execution(* com.tutorialspoint.*.*(..))")`. But if we want to fire the aspect where i am explicitly mention the aspect or annotation, how would you do that? For example in a particular method of a class if we annotate with some annotation than the particular aspect should be called similar to `@Transaction` in spring. How to do similar thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are possibly two annotatable points you are interested in: the class and/or the method.

If you are interested in the class having a particular annotation, you can use `@within(SomeAnnotationType)` or `within(@SomeAnnotationType *)`. Combine that with execution to pick out execution of any method in an annotated type `execution(* *(..)) && @within(SomeAnnotationType)`

If you are interested in a particular method being annotated you can use `@Pointcut("execution(@SomeAnnotationType * *.*(..))")`. In this case it doesn't matter if the type is annotated. See the annotation just goes at the front of the method signature.

And you can of course combine these two, like Spring does:

```
pointcut executionOfMethodInAnnotatedType:
  execution(* *(..)) && @within(MyAnnotation);

pointcut executionOfAnnotatedMethod():
  execution(@MyAnnotation * *(..));

pointcut executionOfInterestingMethod():
  executionOfMethodInAnnotatedType() ||
  executionOfAnnotatedMethod();
```